# How to show that a topological submanifold is a retract of an open set?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $M \rightarrow N$ is a continuous embedding of a topological (not necessarily smooth) manifold $M$ as a closed subset of a *smooth* manifold $N$.  Do you know a nice way to see that $M$ is a retract of an open set in $N$? I have read that topological manifolds are absolute neighborhood retracts but I think the proof of that fact is too technical for me. I'm also aware of tubular neighborhoods but I don't see a way to produce one without a smooth structure for $M$. Thank you!

Edit: Please feel free to assume that M is compact.